# t test with weights and no equals variances

Tags: r

When the function `t.test` is applied in R, the option of `var.equals = TRUE` or `FALSE` can be chosen according to whether the variances are equal or not.

Well, I'm analyzing data from a survey with weighting and I want to know if there is any equivalent function with weighting, where you can choose the option of equal or not variances.

I suppose the test of normality and equality of variances does not change, when there is weighting, right? (I apply the `lillie.test` and the `var.test`).

Comment: Maybe the question is better for Crossvalidated? https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you have questions about statistical tests, it's best to ask them at [stats.se]. You should know what test you want to perform before you ask how to do it in R here.

Comment: I suggest to start considering the `svymean` and `svyttest` functions of the `survey` package: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139619/r-using-survey-package-to-run-t-test-on-sub-population-of-weighted-data-set

Comment: Ok, thank you very much :)